# Java FileReader FileNotFound issue when reading in the string

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, filereader

I have the following code:

```
    BufferedReader inFromUser =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter: ");

    String m = inFromUser.readLine();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(m));

    String text;

    while((text = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    br.close();
```

And when reading in the string from the user the file can never be found. I don't know what is happening when the string is passed but it becomes unfindable. Although the file is very much there.

I have run tests and when I replace the newFileReader(m) with newFileReader("Lab3/test") the file is found, but when I enter the "Lab3/test" into the system(Via the String m = inFromUser.readLine();) to read it, it's read in and printed as "Lab3/test" but the file reader never finds the file when the string is passed into the file reader(Via m), when the string is the exact same.

I've googled a bit but trying to explain that is a pain.

A thank you in advance, Sam

Comment: For debugging purposes, try this `String m = inFromUser.readLine();
File f = new File(m);
System.out.prinln(f.getAbsolutePath() + "  exists: " + f.exists()); ..`

Comment: I just tried adding the File f = new File(m);

OK when I enter the string the new File(m) works fine.

It picks up the file and I added what you suggested and recieved:

"Enter:  "Lab3/test"
C:\Users\Smithers\Dropbox\Software Engineering Code\Eclipse\Networking\ "Lab3\test" exists: false"

But once again if I pass f into the buffered reader it stills says file not found, which is surely contradictory?

Comment: `new File(m)` will always work, no matter whether the file exists or not. The question is, what does `new File(m).exists()` return. If it `exists()` returns `false`, as it did in your case, then the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Enter the file name without the quotes and spaces or remove the spaces with trim.   String m = inFromUser.readLine(); m = m.trim();

Comment: I changed:
String m = inFromUser.readLine(); 
File f = new File(m); 
to:
String m = inFromUser.readLine();
File f = new File("Lab3/test"); 

And this returned: 
"Enter: 
C:\Users\Smithers\Dropbox\Software Engineering Code\Eclipse\Networking\Lab3\test exists: true"

The only difference I can see is that without entering it to the system their is no space after Networking\ and the Lab3\test is not in quote marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enter the file name without quotes. If you enter it with quotes, then the file name must contain the quotes as well.

If you use file name such as `Lab3/test`, then Java will search for the file in the current working directory. The current working directory is normally where the application was started. I might be easier if you enter the complete, absolute file name, such as `C:\Users\Smithers\Dropbox\Software Engineering Code\Eclipse\Networking\Lab3\test`.

It doesn't matter if you use backslashes or forward slashes.

Comment: I realised this just as you posted this, Thanks for the reading in hints and tips guys.